# Convert DateTime in millisecond iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, datetime

I have the date and time , what i want is the no of milliseconds from the particular date and time

for eg: date is `21-04-2015`
and time on the date(21-04-2015) is `14:23`

then the output in milliseconds is `1429606437692`
 **I want the no of milliseconds from 1970 to todays date up to `14:23` time**
how to get this date time in millisecond in iOS?

**please help and thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following code for getting date and time into Millisecond.

```
NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

For more detail refer [apple documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/index.html)

**----Edited----**

```
NSString *dateString = @"21-04-2015 14:23";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds = [dateFromString timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
```

Comment: this will take only today's date i also want to pass time of today's date..

Comment: So just put your NSDate there only

Comment: i dopnt want millisecond up to todays date but also up to some time in todays date

Comment: @Krunal - Please try this answer. Instead of `[NSDate date]` pass your `date` object which contains date as `21-04-2015 14:23`

Comment: You need to multiply by 1000.0 to get it in milliseconds.

Comment: when i run your code it gives me this output : `1429606380.000000` it should be `1429606437692 `

Comment: @TimJohnsen then output will be  `1429606380000.00000` but actual output for the given date and time is `1429606437692` where is the problem ?

Comment: @Krunal please check millisecond this site  http://goo.gl/kBQzKQ and insert `04/21/2015 14:23:00` it's return `1429606380000`

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to multiply time gap by 1000, as time interval is in seconds and as float value. so simply multiply by 1000. For simple example I add selector

```
 NSDate *lastOneminute = [NSDate date];
[self performSelector:@selector(timeInterval:) withObject:lastOneminute afterDelay:60.0];
```

and after 60 seconds selector call  is :

```
 - (void)timeInterval:(id)timeGap
{
    NSLog(@"time interval : %@",timeGap);

    NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:timeGap] * 1000;
    NSLog(@"milisecond : %f",timeInMiliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
int64_t timeInMilisInt64 = (int64_t)(timestamp*1000);

#pragma mark - Date


   -(void)DateCalc
    {


        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];


        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
        comps.day = 7;
        NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        EndingDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:sevenDays];


    }
```

Comment: I want milliseconds up to some time not only up to todays date

Comment: edited it for  7 days

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
    NSString *dateStr = @"21-04-2015 14:23";

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    ////2014-12-21 08:53:00 +0000 date
    //// 1419151980000 -- milli seconds    
    NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds = [date timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
```

Hope it helps you...!